# Snap mounts showing up in File Explorer

Tags: 20.04, mount, nautilus, snap

As an Ubuntu user, I am more or less forced to use Snap. Especially since I keep everything as close to stock-standard as possible, for the most stable and well supported experience.

With every passing week `snap` grows more invasive, and has most recently made an appearance in the sidebar of my File Explorer (Nautilus).

Here is an example of what I am seeing:

[image: Sidebar shows snap mounts]

The problem in this image is near the bottom - the "116 MB Volume" and "230 MB Volume".

If I click on them, they will auto mount, and I can see that they are related to `snap` when I run the `mount` command:

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_12821.snap (deleted) on /media/USERNAME/disk type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/code_92.snap (deleted) on /media/USERNAME/disk1 type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Is there any way to stop `snap` mounts from showing up here? **Even if I unmount the volumes, they are still there. They ALWAYS show up.**

I never tried to make them mount in the first place - I never ran the `mount` command, or messed around with `snap` at all. They just suddenly showed up after about 14 days of uptime. Restarting seemed to fix it.

I have also never done anything special with the `/media/` folder, or configured it to be different in any way. I don't know why they mount there. It's the same place that my USB's auto-mount to, so I assume it's an Ubuntu default.

My `/etc/fstab` has nothing at all to do with this. **There is nothing interesting in this file.**

```
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /                    ext4   errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=XXXX-XXXX                            /boot/efi            vfat   umask=0077        0       1

# 2TB HDD
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /home/addison/hdd    ext4   defaults          0       0

# Swap Partition
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX none                 swap   sw                0       0

# MariaDB tmpfs/ramdisk
none                                      /mnt/mariadbtmp      tmpfs  rw,relatime,size=2G 0 0

# Several random NFS mounts
192.168.X.X:/redacted                     /mnt/redacted        nfs4   defaults,_netdev,soft,rw,bg,timeo=180 0 0
192.168.X.X:/redacted                     /mnt/redacted        nfs4   defaults,_netdev,soft,rw,bg,timeo=180 0 0
```

I would like it dearly if `snap` could remain as far in the background out of sight as possible.

Comment: I do not know what happened on our system, but normally these .snap files are mounted in a directory under /snap. Yours happen to be mounted under /media/$USER so consequently also show up in the file manager. Just try "ejecting"

Comment: That's the thing. **They show up there whether they are mounted or not.** I cannot get rid of them no matter what I try.

Comment: I know you said "I keep everything as close to stock-standard as possible", but why are they being mounted in /media???? as vanadium pointed out, that is the problem. I just saw a question posted today about wanting to install their /snap directory in another location because the space on the root partition... did you make some similar kind of config change?

Comment: @WU-TANG - your comment actually makes me think that you didn't read this question at all. I have no idea why the default mount location happens to be `/media/`. I assume that's the Ubuntu default. When I plug in a USB it automatically mounts there as well. It's not like I'm trying to make it mount there lol.

Comment: @Addison It would seem that way, after it was edited... But we Both Know that isn't true. Look in gnome-disks or /etc/fstab to see if a mount point is being designated.

Comment: I'm editing it so that it becomes even more obvious, and so that people don't have to read the comments. `/etc/fstab` has nothing interesting in it. I will now be updating my question to contain this new information.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the mountpoints were in systemD:

```
ll /etc/systemd/system | grep snap
```

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  303 Sep 26 09:54 snap-firefox-1883.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  273 Jul 26 16:55 snap-yq-1805.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  333 Sep 26 09:54 var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  282 Jul 27 22:12 snap-gradle-134.mount
```

You can also list them via `systemctl`:

```
$ systemctl list-units -t mount --all | grep snap
```

```
UNIT                                              LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB     DESCRIPTION                                            
snap-bare-5.mount                                 loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for bare, revision 5
snap-core18-2560.mount                            loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2560
snap-core18-2566.mount                            loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for core18, revision 2566
snap-core20-1611.mount                            loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for core20, revision 1611
snap-core20-1623.mount                            loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for core20, revision 1623
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount            loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 24
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-77.mount            loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 77
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-115.mount           loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004, revision 115
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount           loaded    active   mounted Mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004, revision 119
```

So what I did to get rid of those was:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable snap-firefox-1883.mount
Removed /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/snap-firefox-1883.mount.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-firefox-1883.mount.
$ sudo systemctl disable snap-gradle-134.mount
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-gradle-134.mount.
$ sudo systemctl disable snap-yq-1805.mount
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-yq-1805.mount.
```

There is an open bug
[snap--.mount systemd units left behind](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1950864)

Note: Do not replace `\x2d` by a minus sign, but quote the mount name:

````
$ systemctl disable "snap-yaml\x2dlanguage\x2dserver-20.mount"
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-yaml\x2dlanguage\x2dserver-20.mount.```
````

Comment: \x -> hex code character follows, 2D => 2*16+13 => 32+13 => character code 45 => click on `-` in `characters` (hit Win key, type `char`... click on the icon)

Comment: @Hannu yeah that was my train of thought as well, but the solution is to quote the mount name ;-)