# What are these mounted volumes and how to get rid of them (snaps?)

Tags: software-installation, nautilus, snap, mountpoint

I'm using gnome on 22.04 for a couple weeks and these volumes have appeared on my taskbar.

[image: snaps]

They annoyingly stick around whether mounted or unmounted, and their names are unclear. I suspect they are related to the snap stuff usefully described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406494/snap-mounts-showing-up-in-file-explorer).

Unfortunately, running the commands in the referenced post gives wildly different numbers, and also they are way more than just two of them:

```
$ mount | grep snap | wc -l
27
$ ll /etc/systemd/system | grep snap | wc -l
21
$ systemctl list-units -t mount --all | grep snap | wc -l
25
$
```

I want to do as little damage as possible. How do I find out which ones are in the taskbar? Will it hurt anything to disable *all* the snaps?

@sudodus It is possible that I may have deleted firefox already. See below. Why two? Why is one of type `squashfs` and one is null?

```
$ lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model | grep firefox
loop1                 241.5M                   /snap/firefox/2605                 
loop4                 240.6M squashfs          /snap/firefox/2356
```

Comment: Run `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model` in a wide terminal window. I think you will see the snap loop devices and the [name of the] mountpoints will help explain how they are used. After the loop devices are the drives with their partitions listed. Firefox has loop devices and it is also mounted into a directory of the root partition.

Comment: If you remove all snaps you will also remove Firefox. It is possible to install it from some other source, for example a PPA. I think you should think twice before you remove all snaps, to look at the pros and cons, but I know people who do that. So it is definitely possible. It is also possible to install a Linux distro, that does not use snaps at all.

Comment: @sudodus updated with info above.

Comment: It is possible that different installations mount Firefox via snaps in different ways. What happens when you try to start Firefox? - In my Ubuntu 22.04.2 all the loop devices with snaps have squashfs file systems. I don't know why it looks like that for you. Have you tried to remove the snaps already?

Comment: From @sudodus' comment, I am one such user who's decided to remove snaps from my install of 23.04 desktop. While I think snaps have a place, the maturity of the integration is very poor (IMHO). Also yes, you can run Firefox with snap support (via PPA, which is what I'm doing). So... enjoy the flexibility of Ubuntu :).

Comment: @richbl do you have a particular resource online for that process of de-snapifying?

Comment: @sudodus it seems that upon restart there is no difference whatsoever, including with the ghostly mounted drive icons. I am unclear on why this is so.

Comment: There are certainly still builds 2605 and 2356. I wonder if it needs to be rebooted first, that said, doing so kinda moots the whole point of this post so...

Comment: @Lucky, before you go down the snap-free path, first consider that Ubuntu/Canonical is a big proponent of using snaps, so they will likely to get better integrated increasingly in the future (for this I'm hopeful). That said, there are many threads that discuss how to remove snaps, but [I followed this one for my 23.04 install](https://www.debugpoint.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/), and haven't run into any issues.